# Running a cron at 4 am and 4 pm

Tags: linux, unix, cron

The following cron expression `cron(0 14 ? * MON-FRI *)` basically runs something 4:00 pm from Monday to Friday.

I am wondering if it is possible to modify the expression so I can run something at 4:00 am and 4:00 pm every Monday to Friday.

Comment: Enter the second cron expression with 4:00 am value in it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? i only want one expression that can do both is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this `crontab` line to run `command_name` at 4:00 and 16:00 (4 AM and 4 PM) Monday-Friday:

```
0 4,16 * * 1-5 command_name
```

From [`crontab` manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

```
   The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Cron job description looks different from the general crontab. But to give you an idea of how to achieve what you're looking for:

1. Edit cron-table. Choose your editor.

```
crontab -e
```

2. Add 2 lines cron jobs.

```
* 4 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/...# Your command goes here 04:00 am.
* 16 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/...# Your command goes here 04:00 pm.
```

Comment: Yeah i am basically adding a cron expression in aws cloud watch event rule

Answer (score -1):

4PM (16:00): `0 16 * * MON-FRI`
See [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_16_*_*_MON-FRI)
"At 16:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”

4AM &4 PM  (4:00 & 16:00): `0 4,16 * * MON-FRI`
See [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_4,16_*_*_MON-FRI)
“At minute 0 past hour 4 and 16 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”